# Reference is calling base class methods?

Tags: c++, c++11

What's a reason that a child reference will call its parent's methods instead of its own? I have the parent and child both implementing virtual methods.

Problem --> In this sample of code initial.setup is calling State's setup. <-- Problem

```
void StateMachine::initialState(State& initial)
{   
            initial.setup();
            currentStates.add(&initial);
}

void StateMachine::setup(Actor& actor, HashMap<State>& allStates)
        {
            _actor = &actor;
            _allStates = &allStates;
        }
```

Here is my Controller that gives the statemachine an initial state:

```
HashMap<State> _states; //This is defined in Controller
void PlayerController::setup(Actor& actor)
{   
        //Factory* actorFactory = new Factory();
        //actorFactory->setup();

        _actor = &actor;
        _stateMachine.setup(actor, _states);


        DrinkState drinkState(actor, _stateMachine);
        MineState mineState(actor, _stateMachine);
        SingState singState(actor, _stateMachine);
        BrawlState brawlState(actor, _stateMachine);
        SleepState sleepState(actor, _stateMachine);
        IdleState idleState(actor, _stateMachine);
        CombatState combatState(actor, _stateMachine);

        _states.add(idleState.to_string(), idleState);
        _states.add(mineState.to_string(), mineState);
        _states.add(drinkState.to_string(), drinkState);
        _states.add(singState.to_string(), singState);
        _states.add(brawlState.to_string(), brawlState);
        _states.add(sleepState.to_string(), sleepState);
        _states.add(combatState.to_string(), combatState);

        //Put actor in idle state
        _stateMachine.initialState(_states.getValue(idleState.to_string())); //_states.getValue returns a reference
}
```

Relationship between States.

```
class State
    {   
        protected:
            Actor* _actor;
            IStateCallback* _statemachine;
        public:
            State();
            State(Actor& actor);
            State(Actor& actor, IStateCallback& stateMachine);
            virtual void setup();
            virtual void breakdown();
            virtual void tick(float dTime);
            virtual void registerTransitionCallback(IStateCallback& statemachine);
            virtual void switchState(string nextState);
            virtual string to_string();
            virtual bool operator==(State& s); 
            virtual ~State();
    }; 
class MineState : public State
    {   
        private:
            int successChance;
            int maxGold;
        public:
            ~MineState();
            MineState(Actor& actor);
            MineState(Actor& actor, IStateCallback& statemachine);
            virtual void setup();
            void breakdown();
            virtual void tick(float dTime);
            void switchState(string nextState);
            string to_string();
    };
```

Hashmap's getValue function:

```
template<class T>
    T& HashMap<T>::getValue(string key)
    {   
        int bucket = hashString(key);
        HashNode<T>* temporary = hashMap[bucket];

        while (temporary != NULL)
        {   
            if (key.compare(temporary->getKey()) == 0)
            {   
                return temporary->getValue();
            }   

            temporary = &(temporary->getNextNode());
        }   

        T *ret = NULL;
        return *ret;
        //return (T) NULL;
    }
```

Comment: Can you give us a complete, compilable, minimal example that illustrates the problem? It's quite hard to figure out what you're asking. There's no parent/child relationship in the code you pasted.

Comment: Sure I'll add that. Also made the problem a bit more visible.

Comment: You're giving us lots of irrelevant code and not the relevant code. There's probably some slicing going on somewhere, possible in `getValue`. We need complete code. The [basic idea works](http://codepad.org/DFJgV6Sc), of course.

Comment: Can you show us the function which is supposed to be called, namely `StateMachine::setup()`, and how it is declared in `StateMachine?

Comment: I added both StateMachine::setup(), and HashMap<T>::getValue(). Hopefully this will be enough code.

Comment: @David Schwartz are you sure this even works in general? I tried with std:map, and it didn't work. http://codepad.org/xOPMOZwi

Comment: @user1932934 You made a `map` of `Parent`s, and then you tried to put `Child`s in them. You can't do that. That causes [slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), as I warned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is that `HashMap<State>` contains, well, `State`s. When you call:

```
_states.add(idleState.to_string(), idleState);
```

this is invoking the `State` copy constructor, and storing a base `State` in the hash table -- all the information about the derived class has been lost. You're a victim of slicing.

Since you can't store references in a container, you'll need to do something else instead. It's a bit ugly, but if you change the hash table to:

```
HashMap<State*> _states;
```

and then insert `State` *pointers*, you'll get the polymorphic behaviour you expect. (Of course, a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr` could be used instead of raw pointers.)

Comment: That's how I originally had it, but my professor said it can be done without heap memory.

Comment: In this case, you could allocate your various `State` subclass instances on the stack somewhere where they will live at least as long as the `_states` hash table; as member variables of your `PlayerController` class would be a good option, if that is where `_states` itself lives. Then you still define `_states` as a `HashMap<State*>`, and add the addresses of your stack-allocated instances.

Comment: Hm, that would involve making them members of the class right? My professor doesn't want us to do that either :/.